# Python Version for Ruby's array.pack() and unpack()?

Tags: python, ruby

In Ruby, I could easily pack an array representing some sequence into a binary string:

```
# for int
# "S*!" directive means format for 16-bit int, and using native endianess

# 16-bit int, so each digit was represented by two bytes. "\x01\x00" and "\x02\x00"
# here the native endianess is "little endian", so you should 
# look at it backwards, "\x01\x00" becomes 0001, and "\x02\x00" becomes 0002

"\x01\x00\x02\x00".unpack("S!*")
# [1, 2]


# for hex
# "H*" means every element in the array is a digit for the hexstream

["037fea0651b358c361de"].pack("H*")
# "\x03\x7F\xEA\x06Q\xB3X\xC3a\xDE"
```

API doc for [pack](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-pack) and [unpack](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-unpack).

I couldn't find an uniform and equivalent way of transforming sequence to bytes (or vice versa) in python.

While [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) provides methods for packing into bytes objects, the [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct-format-strings) available has no option for hexstream.

EDIT: What I really want is something as versatile as Ruby's arr.pack and str.unpack, which supports multiple formatting and endianess control.

Comment: and what does `["037fea0651b358c361de"].pack("H*")` do in ruby? (for us ignorants...)

Comment: How about a link to pack/unpack APIdoc?

Comment: @pascalbetz added api doc for them in ruby.

Answer (score 2):

`struct` does only fixed-width encodings that correspond to a **memory dump** of something like a C struct.  You want [`bytes.fromhex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex) or [`binascii.unhexlify`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.a2b_hex), depending on the source type (which is never a list).

After any such conversion, you **can** use [`struct.unpack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) on a byte string containing **any number** of “records” corresponding to the format string; each is decoded into an element of the returned tuple.  The format string supports the usual integer sizes and endianness choices; it is of course possible to construct a format **dynamically** to do things like read a matrix whose dimensions are chosen at runtime:

```
mat=struct.unpack("%dd"%cols,buf)  # rows determined from len(buf)
```

It’s also possible to construct a **lower-memory** [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array) if the element type is **primitive**; then you can follow up with `byteswap` as [Alec A mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56249842/8586227).  NumPy offers [similar facilities](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html).

Answer (score 2):

for a string in the utf-8 range it would be:

```
from binascii import unhexlify

strg = "464F4F"
unhexlify(strg).decode()  # FOO  (str)
```

if your content is just binary

```
strg = "037fea0651b358c361de"
unhexlify(strg) # b'\x03\x7f\xea\x06Q\xb3X\xc3a\xde'  (bytes)
```

also `bytes.fromhex` (as in [Davis Herring's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56249820/4954037)) may be worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`memoryview.cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview.cast), which allows you to change the endianness of an array or byte object.

Storing values as [arrays](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#module-array) makes things easier, as you can use the `byteswap` function.

Comment: actually I was looking for more than just `pack("H*"), also `pack("S>")`.  or shall I say I'm looking for a function as versatile as arr.pack,  but that's another story...